# Prerequisite for Milnor Toplogoy from a Differential Viewpoint

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

I finished Introduction to Manifold by Loring Tu and I am interested to study this book by Milnor. But I didn't take a course in topology (other than the one I learnt from the appendix of Tu's book). Is this sufficient for me to read the book by Milnor?

Comment: For some reason your question occurs twice.

Comment: Milnor's book is intended to be far more elementary than Tu's. You just need basic compactness, connectedness, the derivative as a linear map, and inverse/implicit function theorems.